# WCF related in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

When I run my project on local every thing is fine but when I use my online services http://www.examplecompanyservice.svc then this exception is genreated.

> The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the     content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <link rel="alternate" 
          type="text/xml"           
          href="http://www.convalidatech.co.in/services/AccountService.svc?disco"/>

    <TITLE>AccountService Service</TITLE>

    <STYLE> <!-- stylesheet removed for brevity --> </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY><DIV id'>.....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check that you use the same Binding (e.g. BasicHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding) on both server and client sides. At least those two bindings don't use the same mime type.

Comment: What happened is that there was an Exception when calling your service (most likely a 500 Internal Server Error was reported to IIS), and the response sent to the caller is HTML, just like in a browser. So you need to figure out what exception was thrown. Unit testing can help you do that.